# remote connection to mysql server from Cpanel host

Tags: php, mysql

Hi with this script i am trying to test MySQL connection remotely if open or not on my VPS because i need to use some table info remotely.
this script work whit WAMP(local) and in directadmin(internet) and its show remote connection is open on my VPS but with cpanel i have this error.

```
Unable to Connect to 'my_vps_ip'
```

and my script installed on Cpanel so i need to connect to my VPS remotely from Cpanel host.
My question is that if need to enable something in Cpanel to work this script?

```
$dbname = 'b3';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbhost = 'my_vps_ip';
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");
$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result     = mysql_query($test_query);
$tblCnt     = 0;
while ($tbl = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tblCnt++;
    #echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";
}
if (!$tblCnt) {
    echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
}
```

For more info look this 2 link:

1) in my directadmin panel:     http://plusmaster.ir/test.php    WORK

2) in my Cpanel host: http://xlrstats.ir/app/webroot/con.php     NOT WORK

Comment: which vps provider you are using?

Comment: Is your MySQL database actually open to the public? This would seem like something that wouldn't normally happen. Could you upload that to the VPS and set the IP to be 127.0.0.1 and see what happens then?

Comment: i have shared server with godaddy it is open for remote access because i have windows server. if you go through linux with godaddy it is not for remote access of mysql

Comment: Look with cpanel i canot connect to my vps remotely but in other panel i can connect to my vps mysql server. i think my host provider disabled something or bloked something cuz i cannot connect to my vps MySQL server from cpanel host